# How do I merge two data frames on one column if the column has a different name in each dataset?

Tags: r, merge

I have two dataframes `df1` and `df2`. `df1` has column "ID" while `df2` has column "ID_NUMBER".

Here's `df1` in comma separated format:

```
ID, ANIMAL
1, dog
2, alligator
4, cat
5, cougar
```

And `df2`

```
ID_NUMBER, WEIGHT
1, 100
2, 1000
3, 12
5, 125
```

How do I merge these two datasets on `df1$ID`/`df2$ID_NUMBER`, keeping only the rows where they have the ID number in common?

Comment: You can try `merge(df1, df2, by.x = 'ID', by.y = 'ID_NUMBER')`

Comment: @Gopala My apologies. I updated my question to better reflect my dataset.

Comment: Are they in some file?

Comment: @Gopala I read them in from separate .CSV files, if that's what you mean

Comment: If you already have those data frames, the command I gave you should work. What part of it is not working?

Comment: @Gopala My mistake. Your answer works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the output. Is this not what you want?

```
df1 <- read.table(text = 'ID, ANIMAL
                          1, dog
                          2, alligator
                          4, cat
                          5, cougar', header = TRUE)
df1
df2 <- read.table(text = 'ID_NUMBER, WEIGHT
                          1, 100
                          2, 1000
                          3, 12
                          5, 125', header = TRUE)
df2
merge(df1, df2, by.x = 'ID.', by.y = 'ID_NUMBER.')
  ID.    ANIMAL WEIGHT
1  1,       dog    100
2  2, alligator   1000
3  5,    cougar    125
```